# Whoops\Exception\ErrorException Declaration of Gantry must be compatible with Twig\TokenParser\TokenParserInterface

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

I'm using Gantry on WordPress with Helium theme. I'm not sure what I did, but when I try to access the theme I get this error. I can't access the theme. What did I do?

PHP is 7.2. I've tried deactivating plug-ins, with no luck. I'm a noob, but I bet this makes sense to someone and it's an easy hack to fix.

> Whoops\Exception\ErrorException Declaration of Gantry\Component\Twig\TokenParser\TokenParserPageblock::parse(Twig_Token $token) must be compatible with Twig\TokenParser\TokenParserInterface::parse(Twig\Token $token)

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2886) open about this at github

Comment: some one mentioned that there are 2 versions installed of twig, gantry comes with 1.x and somewhere 2.x is also on the server.  i have not been able to locate this other version.?

Comment: ok found the conflict, it was with Mailpoet.  Mail poet has twig.

Answer (score 0):

It is a twig conflict with mailpoet.